# Can I turn Windows Bitlocker back on after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: encryption, windows-10

I'm installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my new laptop, it came with pre-installed Windows 10 and I'm required to disable Bitlocker to install Ubuntu, the question is, can I enable it after the installation?

Comment: Was this installed on a different partition and you have a dual boot? If so, Windows Bitlocker should not touch any partition that is not mapped by the os  and configured to encrypt it.

Comment: @Pizza Yes, I just finished installing Ubuntu on a different partition and with dual boot. I understand that Windows Bitlocker won't touch any partition other than the Windows partition itself. What I am concerned about is if I turn Bitlocker back on, it might mess up GRUB or something else related to partition mapping.

Comment: @CaioMars Hi there, have you tried reenable bitlocker? If so, is there any problem with the dual boot?

Comment: @L_K Man, I think I did but I can't be completely sure, I remember I had to reconfigure GRUB but then I ended up removing Windows not long after. Let us know how it goes for future reference.

Comment: @CaioMars Thanks for you information.